# How to link properties between the original and duplicated object?

Tags: physics, properties

How can I get the following behavior?

1. I make a linked duplicate of an object (in my case an object with a rigid body physics)
2. I change the Mass value of the rigid body property from the original object, so 1 kg becomes 2 kg
3. When I now select the linked duplicate the mass is still 1 kg. This is also the case when I change the mass value of the original object in object mode.

Is that even possible with Blender? I don't want to update each time all duplicates whenever i changed the properties of the original object.

Comment: I don't think linking is possibe, but you can copy the setting easily everytime you modify something. Select all the rigidbodies, the modified must be the active, then select: Object>>Rigid Body>>Copy from Active.

Comment: Hi @FFeller, thanks for the tip. Works like a charm!